# What use would a D flip-flop being fed an analog signal have?

Tags: analog, flipflop

I'm contemplating a non-electronic system that is analogous to a D flip-flop being fed an analog signal and a fixed-frequency clock. The system has an analog input which changes over time. The output of the system is a single bit. The analog input is sampled at fixed intervals. The output goes high if the input exceeds one value, and goes low if the input deceeds a lower value.

I feel like this circuit has a name or common application, but I can't track down what it might be.

Comment: Schmitt trigger , normally inverter output 1/3 to 2/3Vcc thresholds. 'HC14

Comment: but this not the same as a D FF, it is just a hysteretic input.

Comment: i think a D flip-flop **does** have hysteresis.  that positive feedback is how it remembers its state.  so i think your first comment is correct.

Comment: This is called a clocked comparator. It could be implemented with a Schmitt trigger on the D input, but most usually with a comparator. You would use it where you interface into a larger synchronous system with fixed timing domains.

Comment: Another name is *latched comparator*. The hysteresis is not a standard feature, but easily added with a feedback resistor.

Comment: Feedback from a latched value is NOT how you add hysteresis: the input signal can go through many cycles between latch updates.  Positive feedback has to be from an input-following amplifier output to make hysteresis.

Comment: Phrasing in the question is unclear: 'output goes high if...' could just mean there's a guaranteed level for "high" and a different guaranteed level for "low", i.e. logic margin and not hysteresis.

Comment: Stephen, are you done with this Q and A now. If needing clarification, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output bit stream is low-pass-filtered and fed back and subtracted from the analog input, you have a first-order delta-sigma tracking converter.

Comment: Fascinating idea!

Answer (score 4):

> The output goes high if the input exceeds one value, and goes low if
>   the input deceeds a lower value.

That sentence describes a Schmitt trigger: -

[image]

Top signal is the input. Middle single is a normal comparator output. Bottom signal is the Schmitt trigger output - notice how it switches high when the analogue input passes the high trigger threshold and only returns to a low output when the analogue input falls below the low trigger input value.

> The analog input is sampled at fixed intervals.

That implies a sample and hold circuit: -

[image]

It sounds like you are describing a schmitt trigger being fed from the output of a sample and hold circuit that, in turn, is fed from the analogue input.

> The output of the system is a single bit.

Yes it is, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

It's an A/D converter, of course.   Whatever the D threshold is, at clock time the
Q and /Q outputs very quickly settle on a digital representation of the
one-bit digitization  of the input value (0 for under-threshold, 1 for over-threshold).

A high-resolution digitization, it isn't.   But, the captured value is
sampled at a very precise time.

Comment: it's a Schmitt trigger.

Comment: If there are two thresholds, that's not a D input to a flip/flop.  And, if there's a master clock, it's not a Schmitt trigger.   Maybe a Schmitt trigger with a latch?

Comment: any gate has a different `OFF` threshold than `ON` threshold.  and the difference between the two thresholds is called the *"noise margin"*.  (oops. i got that terminology wrong, the *noise margin* is the difference of the output voltage range and input range for each logic state.)  i guess you can call it a clocked Schmitt trigger.

Comment: If the signal were DC coupled, it might have margins, but AC coupling happens, too.  The size of the Schmitt deadband might mean that the A/D conversion just rounds off toward a no-change.